# What does KP mean in keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: shortcut-keys, mate, ubuntu-mate

In Ubuntu MATE, I'm looking at the tiling shortcuts but I'm not sure what KP means. For example `Ctrl+Alt+KP Right` for Tile window right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

KP stands for **K**ey**P**ad.  In this case it's the keypad's right pointer.